# How to get MySQL primary key of a row previously looked up?

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, database

```
$query_check_domain_exists = "SELECT * FROM schools where domain ='$email_domain'";
$result_check_domain_exists = mysqli_query($d_schools, $query_check_domain_exists);
$school_ID_result = ?
```

The $school_ID_result variable needs to contain the school_ID (primary key) of the row it just looked up (there will only be one).

Comment: Can you show sample table data and a sample of what you wish to retrieve?  "SELECT *" returns the complete row including any fields that are primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and then get the `school_ID` from array:

```
$query_check_domain_exists = "SELECT * FROM schools where domain ='$email_domain'";
$result_check_domain_exists = mysqli_query($d_schools, $query_check_domain_exists);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$school_ID_result = $row['school_ID'];
```